# Calling private parent class method from parent class (django)

Tags: python, django, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to call a redefined private method from an abstract parent class. I am using django if that matters.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    def method1(self):
         #do somthing
         self.__method2()

    def method2(self):
         pass # I also tried calling up a prent method with super

class child(Parent):
    def method1(self)
        super(Child, self).method1()

    def __method2(self):
        #do something
```

I get a

```
AttributeError: "'Chil' object has no attribute '_Parent__method2'"
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I should probably add that it works perfectly if method2 is not private (method2 instead of __method2).

It's easy to do in C++ but I am not sure how to do it with python

Comment: That's because C++ actually *has* private attributes, and does not do name mangling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial double underscores prevent polymorphism since both the method definition *and* the method call get mangled, to two different names. Replace with a single underscore to fix this.

Also, double underscores are *not* used for "private" attributes, and you should discard whatever reference told you that they are. They're used for MI disambiguation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to re-read the use of simple and double undrscores. BTW, thanks for all your answers, you are a great help Ignacio. Much appreciated ;-)

Comment: The "reference" you instructed to discard is from the python help documentation, just so you know.